# Help me please decode the string (looks like gzip but it is not)

Tags: python

The software sends to the main server such string:

```
\x1f\xe2\x80\xb9\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00E...\x03\x00\x00"

decode_gzip(body)
```

Later I've tried to decode it through different online decoders and in python like bz2, zip and rar string - nothing.

What can I try next?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Have you tried Cyber Chef, yet?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've played with CyberChef for 2 hours but without any success...

Comment: I have found that post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124206/read-and-process-gzip-from-pub-sub where is the problem with ungzip of the data of the same 100% structure `b'\x1f\xe2\x80\xb9\x08\...\x06\x00\x00'`. It is written that "the gzip compression is performed using an external tool.". But he also was not able to ungzip it.